# Realistically, how does Captain Marvel know to rescue them?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, Stark and Nebula are adrift in space on the Benetar.

How could Captain Marvel know to rescue them? Or was it just blind luck?

Comment: Dude there's no such thing as *blind luck*

Answer (score 14):

**She was told to go save them by the other Avengers.**

1. In Captain Marvel, we see Carol give Fury a space-page allowing him to contact her.
2. During the credits for Infinity War, we see Fury activate the space-pager right before he disintegrates.
3. During the credits for Captain Marvel, we see Carol being summoned to Avengers HQ by the space-pager, and meeting the Avengers, shortly after Thanos snaps everyone away.

If we assume that all of these scenes are canon (and not simply promotional material for  the next movie), then it follows that scene 3 takes place while Tony and Nebula are drifting in space. We can thus assume that Steve and the gang told Carol to go look for them.

Comment: How do they know where Stark and Nebula is?

Comment: @YongQuan They could sense the stones being used from the Garden, perhaps they detected the stones in use on Titan, and so she went there first?

Comment: @YongQuan Maybe Rocket has a way to track his/Quill's ship and knew exactly where it was

Comment: Right. The other Avengers and Captain Marvel had some guesses as to where where they might've gone (e.g. Titan) and presumably Nebula and Stark were along a direct route from Titan to Earth, since they knew their ship was damaged and had no reason to take a scenic route.

Answer (score 6):

## It's not clear.

Certainly, it seems to be *blind luck* but it's possible that Captain Marvel was tracking Thanos and was heading to Earth after visiting Titan.

Since the *Benetar* was heading back the same way it's reasonable to assume that Captain Marvel would have come across the ship on the way.

Comment: She didn't find them "on the way"; she'd already been to Earth in this era, as shown by the two arrivals (one after rescuing these guys, and another at the end of Captain Marvel). So it seems more logical that she was dispatched back out to find the stranded folk

Answer (score 3):

Captain Marvell has spread herself pretty thinly.  As she says

> There's thousands of worlds, all going through the same issues as you

So she's where she needs to be, when she needs to be there.

***How*** she knows where she's most needed is unknown, but she turns up  to rescue

> Tony Stark and bring him home

when they (and the universe at large) needs it.  It's clear that when she's not on-screen, she's off being super-heroic someplace else that really needs her.

Comment: Since her powers in MCU are derived from the Tesseract (speculation: which provides fuel for a warp drive by tunneling fusion energy from the hearts of a binary star system? Eh?), she can probably travel pretty fast. In Endgame, we see her doing "recon" to determine that Thanos is the only sentient being on his entire planet, and it takes only a couple of seconds. Finding Tony in 22 days is still pretty lucky, but it's not like she had to know exactly when and where to show up.

Answer (score 1):

The ship must have sent some distress SOS signal for 21-22 days in a row. Plus the ship shouldn't be far from Titan. Obviously we don't how long Captain Marvel have spent searching for them in the open universe.

Comment: Signals don't travel between star systems in 21-22 days